# moving dynamic disk from Windows to another Windows computer when original Windows is not available

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, dynamic-disk

How do I mount dynamic disk on new system without access to the old OS ?

I need to move Dynamic data disk from old Windows XP (Pro, SP3) system, where disk crashed,  to new Windows system without having access to the old OS.

On new system, Dynamic disk shows as "Dynamic - Foreign".

Microfoft has instructions for moving Dynamic Disk [1].

But Microsoft assumes having access to the *old system*. But I do *not* have acess to the old system.   I am struck with "Dynamic - Foreign" static of the disk on new system.

Thanks
WinXP Pro SP3

[1]
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779854(WS.10).aspx
Move Disk to another computer.

Comment: Try testdisk...u can recover data..http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/411558/non-destructively-convert-offline-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk-using-testdisk-too

Answer (score 5):

Disk management has a ["import foreign disk"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771775.aspx#BKMK_4) feature. No  need to convert and risk data loss, just import the drive in disk management.

> A dynamic disk's status is Foreign.
>
> Cause:  The Foreign status occurs when you move a dynamic disk to the local computer from another computer running Windows 2000, Windows XP Professional, Windows XP 64-Bit Edition, or the Windows Server 2003 operating systems. A warning icon appears on disks that display the Foreign status.
>
> In some cases, a disk that was previously connected to the system can display the Foreign status. Configuration data for dynamic disks is stored on all dynamic disks, so the information about which disks are owned by the system is lost when all dynamic disks fail.
>
> Solution:  Add the disk to your computer's system configuration so that you can access data on the disk. To add a disk to your computer's system configuration, import the foreign disk (right-click the disk and then click Import Foreign Disks). Any existing volumes on the foreign disk become visible and accessible when you import the disk.